# How can I add an old email as attachment in replying to a more recent email in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I would like to attach an old email as attachment in replying to recent email in thunderbird. How can I go about achieving the same?

I can go to *Message-->Forward As--> Attachment* in the old email but doing so I loose context of the current email. I would like to do this in context of replying to the current email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options:

- Open the compose window for the new email, then drag-and-drop the old email into it. Note that you need to drag the old email to the attachment area of the compose window (to the right of the address fields in the default config). Dragging to the email body does not seem to work.
- Save the old email to a file (select old email, then File/Save as.../ save as .eml file). Then attach the file to the new email like a normal file attachment - Thunderbird will automatically detect that it's an email, and will attach it with the correct MIME type message/rfc822.

And BTW: It seems you're not the only one who has trouble finding this feature. There is an enhancement request to add an option "Attach email" to the attachment button: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=380256

Answer (score 1):

You could drag the message from the list into the new email (drop anywhere below the menu and above the body, i.e. where the addresses go), which will add it as an attachment.